# NodeJs/Typescript what to deploy to prod, not working

Tags: node.js, express, typescript

I have a NodeJs app that I've built with typescript. I'm using gulp-develop-server. It works great in development. Now i want to deploy it to a ubuntu server and i'm having problems with modules not found.

I have a dist folder that contains the transpiled javascript and then the node_modules folders at the same level as the dist folder deployed.  When I run node on the server I get module not founds.  node does find the node_modules folder, correctly, but typically, the modules not found are dependencies of dependencies.

What should I be deploying and how do I get node to use the node_modules folder correctly?

This is how I'm calling node.  node_modules is at the same level as ./dist. I'm also using express.

```
node ./dist/index.js
```

Comment: Maybe you're copying files over incorrectly? This might be outside the scope of a programming question. The only hope we have of helping you out is knowing exactly which modules are missing, seeing your `package.json`, and seeing your code that imports the modules.

Comment: Are you running `npm install` on the server? That is very important. Unless you know what you are doing, you should _never_ copy / deploy a `node_modules` folder directly. Always let `npm` rebuild it. There are modules that use C++ code that can break if you deploy it to a different operating system. There are also modules that use `postinstall` scripts and symlinks and other nonsense that will break even if you are merely deploying to another identical machine.

Comment: @SethHolladay - good tip. make an answer and mark it as such.  thanks so much,